# Get data from database and add it into text-box C# wpf

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, textbox, sqldatareader

why I do not get anything in my textbox when I run the program? I have my methods in class can anybody give me any hint I can solve this issue.

MainWin code

```
   *List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

    DBManager dB = new DBManager();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Card card = new Card();

        InitializeComponent();
        dB.GetCards(cards);
        txtQuestion.Text = card.Question;
        lblCardsList.ItemsSource = cards;
        GetRandomCards();
        DisplayCardQuestion();

    }

    private void GetRandomCards()
    {
        Card card = new Card();
        Random random = new Random();
        int rndCard = random.Next(1, 100);
        for (int i = 0; i < rndCard; i++)
        {
           cards.Add(card);
        }


    }
    private void DisplayCardQuestion()
    {
        Card card = new Card();

            lblCardNum.Content =card.CardID;
            txtQuestion.Text = card.Question;
            txtTitle.Text = card.Title;

       }*
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that `dB.GetCards(cards)` returns a `List<Card>`.  If that is the case, use `cards = dB.GetCards(cards);` instead.

Also, in your `GetRandomCard` method, it's going to add the same `card` onto your `cards` `List` `rndCard` times.  If you're trying to pick a Random Card from `cards`, you should rethink your logic.

Comment: I tried  cards = dB.GetCards(cards); but did not work

Comment: There are just too many unknowns with this.  Like, what do the `DBManager` and `Card` classes actually do and are they actually instantiated correctly?  I'm not asking you to answer that question here but would rather ask that you debug it in Visual Studio and set break points to step through every method that you wrote and validate what is actually going on.  Good luck!